# ReactiveUI: How to combine several observales and one property and use ToProperty()

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I am fighting a little bit for a while with my small ReactiveUI based project. At this stage I ended up with a prolbem that was not satisfactory solved. Certainly it is about listening to changes and reacting on it.

So I have a nice View Model. Lets call it `PathViewModel` with one Property `IsEnabled` and two "sub view models" `AnalyzeViewModel`and `ReactionViewModel`. All view models derive from `ReactiveObject` (as supposed). Then there is still another property on `PathViewModel` named `TextView` that is meant to be set. Some declarations:

```
public class PathViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
     //.ctor sets sub view models properly
     private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> textview;
     public PathAnalyzeViewModel AnalyzeViewModel { get; }
     public PathReactionViewModel ReactionViewModel { get; }
     public bool IsEnabled { get => this.isEnabled; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.isEnabled, value); }

     public string TextView => this.textview.Value;

     ....
}
```

What I am trying to do is: When any property of any of the two view models changes or if `IsEnabled` changes then assign some value to `TextView`.

I tried the following approaches in my .ctor but it is either not compilable or results in an empty property `TextView`

```
        this.WhenAnyObservable(
            x1 => x1.AnalyzeViewModel.Changed,
            x2 => x2.ReactionViewModel.Changed,
            x3 => x3.ObservableForProperty(x => x.IsEnabled, false, true))
        .Select(f => SomeString()).ToProperty(this, x => x.TextView, out this.textview, string.Empty);
```

or

```
        Observable.CombineLatest(
            this.AnalyzeViewModel.Changed,
            this.ReactionViewModel.Changed,
            this.WhenAnyValue( z => z.IsEnabled).StartWith(true), (p0, p1, p2) => true)
            .Select(f => SomeString()).ToProperty(this, x => x.TextView, out this.textview, string.Empty);
```

I finally ended up just listening to my own `Changed` but that was not satisfying. I tried to be more acurate by `Where`ing on the property name (see comment) but that refused to work:

```
        this.WhenAnyObservable(
            x1 => x1.AnalyzeViewModel.Changed,
            x1 => x1.ReactionViewModel.Changed,
            x1 => x1.Changed)  //.Where(wf => wf.PropertyName == nameof(this.IsEnabled))
            .Select(f => SomeString()).ToProperty(this, x => x.TextView, out this.textview, string.Empty);
```

So how would an experienced ReactUI developer handle this problem? can it be so hard?

This works but only for the property:

```
IObservable<IObservedChange<PathViewModel, bool>> obsEnabled =    this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.IsEnabled);
   obsEnabled.Subscribe((a) => Console.Write(a.Value));
```

Comment: Well, I still hope someone could answer that. But seems hard. If there is another way around....that's great, too